# Horizontal White Space Between DIVS

Tags: css

I have been trying to build a very simple layout where everything flows vertically but as soon as I add any content to one of the divs, it creates whitespace between the div below it.

Here is an image for an example: http://chriswebbonline.com/imagelinks/help.jpg

Here is my HTML

```
<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="header">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>

<div id="chat">
<p>.</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
<p>.</p>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS

```
body {
    background-color:#777;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

#container {
    width:100%;
    }

#header {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;
    }

#chat {
    background-color:#EEE;
        }

#footer {
    background-color:#000;
    }
```

I would like to know how to stop the whitespace from automatically appearing.

~Chris

Comment: I'm pretty sure your `p`'s margins are bleeding out of the `div`s. What happens if you change the `p`s to an inline element like a `span`, or if you set `margin` to `0` for `p` elements?

Comment: This is solved, thanks! I started using Dreamweaver and I have always used notepad. It seems Dreamweaver adds the p tags automatically.

Comment: Dreamweaver tends to do irritating or against-specification things. I would recommend sticking with something else. If you want a beefed up text editor, then [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) are excellent choices. Both have syntax highlighting for many different code languages, web languages included. For a feature-rich IDE, the three main Java IDEs have decent to excellent web support: [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/), and [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/). All of these are free, too!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
p {
   margin : 0;
}
```

paragraph tag margin is not 0 by default

Answer (score -1):

Just a hunch, but try:

```
<div id="header">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div><div id="chat">
<p>.</p>
</div><div id="footer">
<p>.</p>
</div>
```

(No whitespace between opening and closing tags.)